# adjust the width of the input that correspond to the value length of the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an auto resize like input, like when the user type in, the input will adjust automatically to fit the value inside the input but seem's I can't make it right or working. Any ideas, help please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('input',function(){
    $(this).css('width',$(this).width()+$(this).val().length );
  });
});
```

```css
input{border:1px solid red;width:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="text">
```

Comment: Your current code is definitely changing the width of the input, but I take it it's not changing it how you'd like? Perhaps tell us how you'd like it to be?

Comment: I want to make the width of the input automatically adjust as user type in, the width of the input should correspond to the value length of the input so that the value of the input fits in the input like the value is not cut out when the value contains a long string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your goal is for it to be just as wide as necessary, maybe with a 30px buffer, then the issue is you're *adding* to the width every time rather than recalculating it from scratch. It would also help if you knew how wide a character might be, so probably best to set the font size specifically or even use another hidden element to measure how wide the rendered text is; here I use a `span` for that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('input',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the value
    var val = $this.val();
    
    // Put it in the hidden span using the same font information
    var $hidden = $(".hidden");
    $hidden.text(val);
    
    // Set the input to the span's width plus a buffer
    $this.css('width', $hidden.width() + 30);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  border:1px solid red;
  font-size: 14px;
  width:30px;
}
.hidden {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<span class="hidden"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ...and this would be "not useful" how, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using ***`contenteditable-span`*** in this case, i hope it helps.

```css
#test{border:1px solid red;width:30px;}
```

```html
<span id="test" contenteditable>I'm trying to make an auto resize like input</span>
```

Comment: I like that idea.

Comment: I like the idea but as my requirement, I prefer input not span.